# Is there a way to avoid the RTL?

Tags: delphi

I've been playing with something in Delphi where the RTL is not allowed. It's a kind of dll.

After picking apart the PE (Portable Executable) file format, i realized that all PE files have an *"Entry Point"*. This is the first thing that Windows calls after the module (exe or dll) is loaded.

The *name* of function that resides at this entry point, and it's implied parameters, depend on the kind of PE it is:

- Dynamic Link Library (*.dll): **`DllMain`**

  ```
  function DllMain(hinstDLL: HINST; fdwReason: DWORD; 
        lpvReserved: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
  ```
- Executable (*.exe): **`WinMain`**

  ```
  function WinMain(hInstance: HINST; hPrevInstance: HINST; 
        lpCmdLine: LPSTR; nCmdShow: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  ```
- Device Driver (*.sys): **`DriverEntry`**

  ```
  function DriverEntry(DriverObject: PDriverObject; 
        RegistryPath: PUnicodeString): NTSTATUS; stdcall;
  ```

In Delphi, this *Entry Point* is the code that sits in your main project file.

In the case of a DLL, it is possible to read the parameters passed to our "DllMain" by `LoadLibrary`. If you put a breakpoint at the *EntryPointAddress*:

[image]

you can see the three parameters on the stack:

[image]

All you would have to do is capture them:

```
library Project1;

function DllMain(hinstDLL: HINST; fdwReason: Cardinal; lpvReserved: Pointer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
    Result := 1; //Windows uses FALSE=0, TRUE=1. Delphi uses False=0, True=-1
end;

begin
    //Code in here is run during DllMain.
    //i.e. DllMain does not return until this code completes.
    asm
        { Get the parameters to DllMain that Windows passed to us:
                [ESP+4] hinstDLL
                [ESP+8] fdwReason
                [ESP+12] lpvReserved
        }
        MOV eax, [ESP+12];  //push lpvReserved onto the stack
        PUSH eax;
        MOV eax, [ESP+8];  //push fdwReason onto the stack
        PUSH eax
        MOV eax, [ESP+4];  //push hinstDLL onto the stack
        PUSH eax;

        CALL DllMain;       //Call our DllMain function
                            //DllMain leaves BOOL result in EAX
   end;
end.
```

## But there's an RTL

The problem is that there is more than just **my** code in there. The compiler inserts hidden code just **before**, and just **after**, my code block in the project file:

[image]

Essentially, the *real* `DllMain` code contains:

```
function DllMain(hinstDLL: HINST; fdwReason: Cardinal; lpvReserved: Pointer): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
    SysInit._InitLib(InitTable, hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpvReserved);

    asm
        MOV eax, [ESP+12];  //push lpvReserved onto the stack
        PUSH eax;
        MOV eax, [ESP+8];  //push fdwReason onto the stack
        PUSH eax
        MOV eax, [ESP+4];  //push hinstDLL onto the stack
        PUSH eax;

        CALL DllMain;       //Call our DllMain function
                            //DllMain leaves BOOL result in EAX
   end;

   System._Halt0;
end;
```

Now, this preamble call to `_InitLib` does wreak some havoc with trying to pull the values of `hinstDLL` and `fdwReason`; but that's not an insurmountable problem (e.g. you can still find them at `EBP+8`,`+12`, and `+16`).

But my issue is that the RTL links to code that isn't always available. Looking at the *Import Directory Table*, you can see that it needs:

- `user32.dll` (e.g. `MessageBoxA`)
- `kernel32.dll` (e.g. `VirtualAlloc`, `VirtualFree`, `CloseHandle`)

## Can i avoid the RTL?

Is there a compiler option, or a define, that can strip out all the guts of `System._InitLib` and `System._Halt0`? Or just have the compiler not place them into:

```
function DllMain(hinstDLL: HINST; fdwReason: Cardinal; lpvReserved: Pointer): LongBool; stdcall;
begin
   SysInit._InitLib(InitTable, hinstDLL, fdwReason, lpvReserved);

   //...
   System._Halt0;
end;
```

It's obviously a special bit of smarts on the part of the compiler that knows to create them. And what gets implicitly placed in the **EntryPointProcedure** changes depending if it's a **Library** or **Application** binary.

## Bonus Chatter: The case of the missing `WinMain` arguments

The `WinMain` entry point is documented to pass four parameters:

```
function WinMain(hInstance: HINST; hPrevInstance: HINST; 
          lpCmdLine: LPSTR; nCmdShow: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
```

- `hInstance: HINSTANCE`
- `hPrevInstance: HINSTANCE`
- `lpCmdLine: LPSTR`
- `nCmdShow: Integer`

Which is why i couldn't figure out why the arguments weren't being passed to the EntryPointFunction:

[image]

I was debugging further and further back in the stack. I tried other debuggers. Windows just wasn't passing the appropriate parameters to the Entry Point function. Then i found [the answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/25/10168020.aspx):

> The operating system calls the function with no parameters

The ***real*** Windows `.exe` entry point function is:

```
DWORD CALLBACK RawEntryPoint(void);
```

aka:

```
function RawEntryPoint(): DWORD; stdcall;
```

> Where do the parameters to WinMain come from, if they aren't passed to the raw entry point?
>
> The language startup code gets them by asking the operating system:
>
> - the instance handle for the executable comes from `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`
> - the command line comes from `GetCommandLine`
> - and the `nCmdShow` comes from `GetStartupInfo`
> - `hPrevInstance` is always `NULL`

So that explains that.

Comment: You'll have to give up dynamic arrays, strings, exceptions, and a lot of other things too. Are you ready to do that? You are trying to make a WinRT DLL perhaps?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan **.exe** -> `WinMain(...)`, **.dll** -> `DllMain(...)`, **.sys** -> `DriverEntry(...)`. I didn't want to mention kernel mode device driver development for fear it would cloud the issue. (*"It's a kind of dll."* Which a driver is; a DLL, with exports, and an entry point)

Comment: I think you'd be far better off with FPC for this: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Target_NativeNT And you should mention that you are targeting drivers. That would make it all so much clearer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've looked at that. There is also [a kit where a guy converts `dcu` to `obj` files](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/delphidriverdevelopmentkit) so that they can be linked using a Microsoft compiler. But i wasn't asking about that. I was asking more about a flag to tell the compiler what to do. With AppType dll it makes _DllInit the entry point. With AppType **application** it makes _ICantRememberWhat the entry point. i was hoping for an Apptype **none**. Or a `-switch` to change the behavior of `dcc32/64.exe`.

Comment: It doesn't exist. You need to hack in your own bespoke `System` and `SysInit`. If you want Pascal device drivers, FPC is your best option.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If there is no option in the compiler, or no define that can be set, then put that in the form of an answer. There's no shame in saying, "Cannot be done" when it's the correct answer!

Comment: It is possible to use [Kithara »RealTime Suite«](http://www.kithara.de/en/products/realtime-suite) with Delphi to compile kernel mode software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can achieve what you desire using the stock compiler/RTL. The compiler expects the presence of `System` and `SysInit` units and indeed uses those units to supply runtime support for many language features. As an example, strings are a language feature that is implemented by way of support functions implemented in the `System` unit.

If you provide replacement `System` and `SysInit` units that the compiler will accept then it is possible to remove the dependencies on user mode modules. However, this is not for the feint of heart.

Since you seem to wish to write kernel mode driver code, I would suggest using FPC.

Comment: Since i would have to have an after-build action to change `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.Subsystem` to `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_NATIVE` from `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI`, i can take that opportunity to `nop` the call. I was just hoping that at some point Bo...Imp...Cod...Embarcadero, with their new OS targets, had exposed to way to not use Windows dlls.

Answer (score 9):

KOL is still alive and kicking and the official website http://kolmck.net (maintained by me) contains examples on how to rewrite the system unit.

Comment: I downloaded it. And i saw the FAQ question ("Is it possible to use KOL (MCK) without uninstalling VCL. If I install KOL (MCK), could it be possible to use VCL without reinstalling the Delphi?"). And i've read the `read1st.txt`; but i don't see how to **use** it. It seems you manage to replace the entire RTL; which is one step from hiding the RTL per-project. But what do i include that causes the compiler/linker to not find/use the RTL?

Comment: In August 2016 the link seems to be dead. Maybe the link should point here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/keyobjectslibrary/

Answer (score 2):

When a DLL is loaded and its main DPR code starts running, you can get the `hinstDLL` value from the RTL's global `SysInit.HInstance` variable, and you implicitly know that the `fdwReason` value must be `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`.  The only value you cannot retrieve during `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` is the `lpvReserved` value because the RTL ignores it rather than save it somewhere.  However, if you want your code to react to other `fdwReason` values, and receive `lpvReserved` values in those other reason states, all you have to do is assign a `DllProcEx` callback that the RTL calls from within its internal `DllMain` entry point, eg:

```
library Project1;

{$R *.res}

procedure MyDllMain(Reason: Integer; Reserved: Pointer);
begin
  // use SysInit.HInstance, Reason, and Reserved as needed...
  case Reason of
    //...
  end;
end;

begin
  DllProcEx := @MyDllMain;
  // The RTL does not expose access to lpvReserved here because 
  // DllProcEx has not been assigned yet when the RTL processes
  // DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH before calling unit initializations. If
  // you need lpvReserved here, you will have to manually pull
  // it from the call stack directly...
  DllProcEx(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, nil);
end.
```